# Fancybox scroll bars showing in chrome and safari not firefox?

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, overflow, fancybox-2

Im am using fancy box on this page http://kimcolemanprojects.com/django_django.html

When you click on a link which displays a video it shows scroll bars that I don't want to be there. It seems to be that The element has been given the style of overflow: auto, but i can not find where that is declared in order to change it. By the way this happens on safari and chrome but not firefox.

Thanks for you time.

angela x

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that there is a browser default that is setting the `overflow` to auto. In that case, you will have to declare `overflow: hidden` on those lightbox elements in your stylesheet.

Also, I'm not seeing scroll bars in Chrome 23 or the latest version of safari.

Comment: hi, thanks for response, I can see when I inspect the element that the fancybox-inner div is given the style overflow: auto, which as you said is causing the problem, However I am trying to target the element  in my css but can't get to it to declare overflow: hidden.

Comment: While it is not recommended for a long term solution, does adding ``overflow: hidden !important;`` work for you? If this does not work, then there is something else afoot. Are you sure there are no other styles targeting the same element?

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. I know something is targeting it as when looking at it in chrome it has the style overflow: auto applied to it. It must be the user agent stylesheet, or could it be something in the js of the fancy box?

Comment: It is possible that fancybox is adding it's own ``!important`` but that shouldn't be the case since the scrollbars are not appearing for me. Try this: in chrome developer tools, select the overlay, expand the "computed styles" dropdown, and find the entry for ``overflow`` and then click on the dropwdown arrow next to it. This should give you a list of the different declarations that are modifying the elements style.

Comment: thanks for this but still can't get to it. It is the fancybox-inner div and no matter how I target it through the css I can't change the element style. That I can see on the chrome developer tools and can change the overflow to hidden which gets rid of the scroll bars, but it doesn't stay that way. As the actual element has the style auto applied somewhere. I think it must be in the javascript of the fancy box.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `scrolling: "no"` option to your script like :

```
$(".fancybox").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
    beforeLoad: function() {
        var el, id = $(this.element).data('title-id');
        if (id) {
            el = $('#' + id);

            if (el.length) {
                this.title = el.html();
            }
        }
    },
    scrolling: "no" //<-- get rid of the scroll bars inside fancybox
});​
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it hasn't stopped the scroll bars. It appears to be only the video elements that have the scroll bars not images.